# Using jQuery animate to have a div slide down from center?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Since regular jQuery animations are not fluent on iOS (`.hide()`, `slideDown()`), I'm attempting to turn my shorthand `.fade()` and `.slideDown()` functions into the longhand `.animate()` functions, so I can then use [jQuery.Animate](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/) plugin to convert these animations to CSS3, while mainiting a jQuery fallback.

I think fading a div using this method should be easy, but attempting to have a div slide down from the center is giving me a headache.

The normal CSS for the div is...

```
.zip{
    width:130px;
    height:70px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-46px;
    margin-left:-76px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    background:rgba(0,155,23,.8) url(overlay.png);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow:0 0 40px #000;
}
```

And then I was using the following to delay, then have the div slide down...

```
$(".zip").delay(1000).slideDown(200);
```

This works fine, obviously, but it won't be picked up by the plugin.

**So, how could I turn that into a function using `.animate()`?**

My attempt:

CSS...

```
.zip{
    display:none;
    height:0;
    padding:0;
    /* Plus everything else */
}
```

jQuery...

```
$('.zip').delay(1000).animate({
    display: "block",
    height: "70px",
    padding: "10px",
});
```

Except this is sliding down from the lefthand corner, not the middle.

**Also**, maybe I'm doing this completely wrong, and there's a much better way to use the CSS3 accelerated transitions on iOS devices while still providing a jQuery fallback, in which case, please share!

Comment: Well if you see what I tried, it was hidden in the way that it had no height or padding to it, and had a `display:none` style on it.

Comment: Do you care about the side to side animation?  .slideDown just slides the bottom of the div downwards, it does not animate the sides outward from the center.

Comment: Not really, I just want it to slide down from the center, if that's what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate the width and margin-left as well. Alternatively, you could animate only the width and set the margin to auto (which means centered horizontally)

Comment: What would an example be? And would this at all effect the position of the element?

Comment: `$(elem).css({width:0,height:0,margin:'auto',display:block}) .delay(1000) .animate({width:130,height:70})` will animate the element from zero size to 130x70 px, while the browser keeps the element centered horizontally.

Comment: This still makes the box slide down from the top left corner.

Comment: You need to set the container to fill the whole page. Give 100% width to the ancestors of the element (unstyled block elements should have 100% width automatically, though)

Comment: Is there a way to do it with keeping the css already set to it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use slideDown()` method:

```
$('.zip').slideDown()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mHR98/1)

Comment: Okay, but I really don't want to use `.slideDown`... the plugin won't recognize it. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: the plugin won't recognize it? why?

Comment: The plugin looks for `$.animate()` and transforms the parameters inside into the CSS3 equivalent.

Comment: Actually, slideDown() uses animate() internally. You could introspect this function if you really want to.

Comment: Could you elaborate @JanDvorak?

Comment: @Charlie the slideDown method is implemented as `function (a,c,d){return this.animate(b,a,c,d)}`. You can verify this by typing `$.prototype.slideDown` into the javascript console - stackOverflow already has the jQuery library included. I guess `b` is a constant object along the lines of `{display:'block', height:'initial'}`

Comment: So, `b` is defined as `{"height":"show","marginTop":"show","marginBottom":"show","paddingTop":"show","paddingBottom":"show"}`.